# Re-using a stimulus action elsewhere on the page?

Tags: stimulusjs, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am wiring up a slack clone [(html/css)](https://codepen.io/viniosity/pen/mdOggmx) and have it so that the reference drawer opens/closes when I click on the x. I am wanting to also open/close it from the navigation area and thought I could just take the same link_to and call it from a different part of the page.

But when I do that, if I'm calling it from within a different target, I get an error

```
Error invoking action "click->navigation#toggle_reference_drawer"
Error: Missing target element "navigation.referenceDrawer"
```

How can I use code inside a data-target to trigger a different data-target?

i.e. what I'm trying to get working is

--navigation partial (link_to doesn't work) --

```
<div data-navigation-target="storyNavLinks">
   <div class ="story">
     <%= link_to "[x]", "#", data: { action: "click->navigation#hide_reference_drawer" } %>
   </div>
</div>
```

-- application partial (link_to works) --

```
  <div data-navigation-target="referenceDrawer">
     <div class='reference box'>
        <%= link_to "[x]", "#", data: { action: "click->navigation#hide_reference_drawer" } %>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong.. I figured as long as the target being referenced is unique and on the page it shouldn't matter where it's being called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure your `data-controller` attribute is on an element that wraps both targets. If that is not possible you can always include the controller twice but the targets will only be scoped to each instance so you will need to add them twice as well.